# Uniform line endings when importing data from excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, newline

In C# (ASP.NET , 2.0) I'm currently importing data from an excel file into a Dataset through OleDb connexion. This works quite well.
I noticed a small issue though : in an Excel field (at least in my file) multiple lines of text are separated with a simple `\n` character. This is a problem because data in my database has `\n\r` line endings all the way. I noticed it when trying to display the imported data and replace the newlines characters (`System.Environment.NewLine`) with `<br>` : data coming from the database was displayed correctly, while data coming from the excel file was on 1 single line.

While I could perfectly adapt this when displaying the data and later when importing it into the database, I think it would be cleaner to adapt my "excel import" class so that line endings are aligned with line endings used in the rest of the application.
There, I know I could loop on all the fields of my dataset and replace `\n`with `\n\r` before returning it but that could (would) probably cause some performance problems and I find this solution even more dirty than simply doing the replacements upon display/insert of the data.

So, is there any cleaner solution I could use in order to do this ? I'm thinking a parameter of the OleDb connexion, or a setting of the OleDbDataAdapter, or a specific flag in the `Fill()` method of the adapter , or even a functionality I don't know anything about yet.

Thanks for helping, or confirm I have no choice but to go the dirty way :-)